# Why "okhttp" internal package source file name start with "-"?

Tags: okhttp

Lately, I found a weird file name beginning with "-" on "okhttp" [source code](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp/src/commonMain/kotlin/okhttp3/internal).

Why "okhttp" internal package source file name start with "-"?

[image]

Comment: Unlike Java, Kotlin files don't require the same name as the class they contain. It must be a convention for the project. I think you will get a better answer if you opened up a GitHub issue with this question.

Comment: Thank you @ashu , but that project is not allowed issue for a question. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a convention taken from Okio https://github.com/square/okio/blob/master/okio/src/jvmMain/kotlin/okio/-JvmPlatform.kt

Effectively makes these completely inaccessible to Java code.[image]